# Pinging in Python with Feedback

Tags: python, subprocess, ping

so I'm such a noob in Python it's painful but I'm trying to come up with a way to PING a site, then spit out an 'if/else' clause.

So far I have this:

```
import subprocess 
command = "ping -c 3 www.google.com"  # the shell command
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,     
stderr=None, shell=True)

#Launch the shell command:
output = process.communicate()

print output[0]
```

Below is where I go awry, here is part two:

```
if output == 0.00
print "server is good"

else
print "server is hosed"
```

Obviously part 2 is not working out.

My question is, how do I "read" the results from the ping (the milliseconds)
    icmp_seq=0 ttl=44 time=13.384 ms

and say "if the ping time is faster than 12.000 ms then do THIS"
else
    "do THAT"

Right now I'm just doing a print but soon I'd like to change that so something else.

Comment: why not just do a get request as a heart beat?

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.Popen` is usually not the one you want. There are convenience functions for all of the simple tasks. In your case, I think you want `subprocess.check_output`:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

There are many ways to parse the resulting output string. I am fond of regular expressions:

```
matches = re.findall(" time=([\d.]+) ms", output)
```

`re.findall` returns a `list` of `str`, but you want to convert that to a single number so that you can do numerical comparisons. Use the `float()` constructor to convert the `str`s to `float`s, and then compute the average:

```
matches = [float(match) for match in matches]
ms = sum(matches)/len(matches)
```

Sample program:

```
import subprocess
import re

# Run the "ping" command
command = "ping -c 3 www.google.com"  # the shell command
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

# And interpret the output
matches = re.findall(" time=([\d.]+) ms", output)
matches = [float(match) for match in matches]
ms = sum(matches)/len(matches)

if ms < 12:
     print "Yay"
else:
     print "Boo"
```

Note that the output of `ping` is not standardized. On my machine, running Ubuntu 14.04, the above regular expression works. On your machine, running some other OS, it might need to be different.

Comment: Thank you - so Popen is like actually opening the terminal, correct? I notice when I do that, it displays the 3 ping lines for viewing. With check_output, it simply displays the 'Yay' or 'Boo'. Is there a way for the script to print out the ping lines?

Comment: Yes, all of the `subprocess` family of functions run commands that you might otherwise invoke on the terminal. The text returned by `check_output("ping")` would be identical to the result of typing `ping` at a command prompt.

Comment: If you'd like my sample program to display the entire output of the ping, add `print output` at the end.

Comment: Thank you! I really hate asking these simple questions but I went through a short python course, did nothing with it for two months (so I forgot most) and usually the response to my question(s) is a url to an article that contains so much tech jargon that I'm more confused after reading it than I was before. So thank you so much.. more questions to come I'm sure. :)